# Node.js server interface with GUI application in Qt

Tags: c, node.js, sockets, real-time

I have created a Webserver architecture in Node.js. I need to create a bridge between this server and an already programmed Qt application.

Comment: What does your C application do? Does it accept an input via command line arguments and just print out a value? If that's the case you might be able to get away with running the executable via the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi

It looks like the stuff that would help you. No need to modify the original sources, just load a shared object, define your functions and you are ready to go. It is similar to python ctypes, which works great for me when I need to call C code from python

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked really well for me is using QProcess

I have started ther server in Qt using QProcess. Here is the code

```
QString program ="/usr/bin/node";
QStringList arguments ;
arguments << "/home/phyvm/Try-8/v7/server.js";
myProcess = new QProcess(this);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score -2):

U can exec any binary using node.js but i'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Then earn that reputation instead of bleeding it by writing comments as answers :)